# Form in while validation doesn't work

Tags: php, database, forms, validation, while-loop

I am trying to validate a "modify" form. The data is received from database so of course i have to put it in a while.

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($categories))
    {
    ?>
<form name="adminEditCategory" action="../db/adminModifyCategory.php" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
    <tr>    
    <td>


    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php print $row['id']; ?>" readonly="readonly" style="width: 20px;" />

    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="name<?php print $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php print $row['name']; ?>" /><span></span>
    </td>
    <td> <img src="../utils/getLogoCategory.php?id=<?php print $row['id']; ?>"  style="max-width:40px; max-height:40px; float: left; margin-bottom: 10px;" align="left" /> </td>
    <td>
    <input type="file" name="attachment<?php print $row['id']; ?>" value="" style="float: right; "><span></span>
    </td>
    <td> <?php print date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['added_date'])); ?>
    </td>
    <td> 
    <select width="294" name="is_deleted<?php print $row['id']; ?>"  style="width: 50px;">
                    <?php               

                        foreach($is_deleted as $id=>$name)
                        {
                        ?>
                            <option value="<?php print $id; ?>" <?php if($id == $row['is_deleted']) print "selected= 'selected'"; ?> ><?php print $name; ?></option>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                  </select><span></span>
    </td>
    <td> <input type="submit" value="Modifica" name="Edit" class="button" onClick="return validateEditCategory(<?php print $row['id']; ?>)" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Sterge" class="button"  name="Delete" onClick="return validateDeleteCategory()">

    </td>

    </tr></form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

This is the validation code:

```
function validateEditCategory(Id)   {
    var valid;
        valid = true;
        // alert (document.forms["adminEditCategory"]["name"+Id].name);
        valid *= checkNume(document.forms["adminEditCategory"]["name"+Id]);
        valid *= checkIsFileGol(document.forms["adminEditCategory"]["attachment"+Id]);  

        return valid > 0;
    }
```

The validation works, but only for the first row. I can't understand why it doesn't validate the rest of the  rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this `<form name="adminEditCategory" action=`
to this `<form name="adminEditCategory<?php print $row['id']; ?>" action=`

and

this `document.forms["adminEditCategory"]`
to this `document.forms["adminEditCategory" + Id]`.

---

In replace, you can reduce all the ID appending to names of inputs. The point is, give all the forms different names, but inside each form you can call all the fields the same, because you already pass the ID in the `<input name='id'>`. But that is not necessary, just shorter and more logical.